# local CSS and JS not found when building project React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, deployment, build

I installed bootstrap, jquery .... with npm used their path from node_modules and it works as development but when I build the project with 'npm run build', all the css is lost, and I can see in developer tools 'network' that the path of css files is node_modules.... which not exist in the build folder.

is there any other to import these file other than manual copy/paste into the build folder,

I can't use cdn. the app won't be available to the internet.

if something is unclear please just do comment.
thank you

Comment: the concept of the issue is common and clear.. but you didn't tell us many things: are you using create-react-app ? are you using another template ? where are you importing these modules (bootstrap,...) or you just install them ?

Comment: sounds like you are including them in html instead of importing `import './path/to/file.css'` in your jsx files

Comment: update: i did import them, when i build the project and serve it with `serve -s build` it goes normal, but with nginx still no css

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI no i didn't use create-react-app, i worked everything with npm

Answer (score 1):

Are you including the CSS in your react file as `import "./path/to/example.css"
in the import section of the react file?
That will make webpack bundle the CSS with your app

Comment: update: i did import them, when i build the project and serve it with `serve -s build` it goes normal, but with nginx still no css

Comment: so when you serve the build folder via nginx, what errors are you getting?

Comment: no errors and it does not serve css, i even tried to add a css folder to the build folder, yet nginx didnt serve it

Answer (score 1):

When I use node_modules for styles and scripts, I use scss and add @import with path into node_modules and for scripts add import with the path to node_modules.

SCSS

```
@import "~bootstrap";
```

JS

```
import 'jquery'
```